# Problems getting rid of Google Mail Archive entries on Outlook for Android

Tags: gmail, outlook

I have my Google Mail account set up in Outlook on both Android and Windows.
On Android there is an Archive folder, on Windows there is not; the Android one appears to be local (though it is not in any way labelled as such).

I have created an ArchivedItems folder in my Google Mail account, and I select all items in the Google Mail Archive from time to time, move them into ArchivedItems, and they then pop up on Outlook for Windows where I can move them to my main Archive folder which lives in another email account.

All well and good, except that the items have a tendency to reappear at some later point in the Google Mail Archive folder on Outlook for Android - not every time, this seems completely unpredictable.

I can see no reference to this problem anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is sign out and sign back in and the archived items should update within the app. Another you can do is re-archive the items on a device that you are able to archive (by un-archiving and rearchiving) and then sign out and back in on the troubled device.

Comment: Thanks but not clear why this would help, given the Archive folder in Outlook for Android is local (or certainly unavailable from Outlook for Windows). And are you saying I would need to  sign out/in every time I moved my Archive items out? Happy to try it but I won't know immediately whether it's worked or not so would be good to understand the logic behind the suggestion.

Comment: You would archive or unarchive everything and then sign out and sign back in, it should work.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why that would work where normal sync does not, but have just tried it (assume you mean the 'reset account' option since there seems to be no mechanism in Outlook for Android for signing the Google account out, I guess because it's the main identity of the 'phone (?)). I will check tomorrow whether it has 'stuck'.

Comment: It appears to have worked, although I really would like to understand the logic here.

Comment: The problem recurred and I have now realised that Google handles this completely differently, via labels, and that effectively the Android Outlook app is unable to process the Archive button sensibly on a Google Mail message. Hence answer un-accepted and Google Mail removed from my Android Outlook (using Gmail app instead, though that's not great either).

Comment: The thing is that you can’t move mail from one archive to another. Also I still need to be aware of what device you’re using. A computer or tablet with outlook? You can archive it with gmail or outlook but the main thing you’ll want to know is when you archive mail it hides it and the only way to find it is to open your tab that says “All mail” it’s always going to be in there if you have your mail synced. I’m sorry if I didn’t help you but I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do. You want to sync with outlook or Gmail on a computer, why do you want to archive them? Can I know why?

Comment: You created an archive folder, that’s not how the archive works, you have to archive it in gmail or outlook, moving it to the archive folder you made by hand won’t automatically archive it. If you want to archive it automatically what you can do is set a filter with gmail. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, apologies for not answering sooner. 1) 'you can’t move mail from one archive to another.' I do so in Outlook on Windows all the time between e.g. Hotmail and my own IMAP email. 2) The problem is local to the Outlook Android app, which I am using on my 'phone. 3) I wanted to be able to archive my incoming Gmail items via the Outlook on Android 'Archive' button and then (later) to move the results to my IMAP Archive folder via Outlook on Windows. This does not work because Gmail's archiving mechanism is quite different from everyone else's (doesn't use an Archive folder).

Comment: 4) I tried setting a filter rule on has:nouserlabels in the Gmail browser interface but it only works if I run it manually since Gmail seems incapable of running filter rules automatically on anything other than mail arriving in the Inbox. 5) Don't worry, it would be nice if Outlook for Android didn't pretend to the uninitiated that the 'Archive' button worked the same for Gmail as for every other email system I have ever seen, but there we are. I'm grateful to you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Outlook for Android is a horrible app in many other ways anyway.

Comment: I’m sorry I wasn’t able to help much but I’m glad I helped a little. If there’s anything else you need you’re welcome to ask. Hopefully someone who is able to help finds this.